# Subsets in axiomatic set theory - ZFC

Tags: set-theory

**A naive question about axiomatic set theory**

I'm trying to teach myself some basic set theory by reading 
*Set Theory for the Working Mathematician* by Krzysztof Ciesielski,
and I'm only in Chapter 1 but I'm already a bit puzzled.

To be concrete, let's work in ZFC.

The axiom of separation says that
if $x$ is a set, $p$ a parameter, and $\varphi$ is a formula, 
then $y=\{u\in x: \varphi(u,p)\}$ is also a set. We can call this $y$
a *subset* of $x$.

Naively, I read this as saying that any formula-delimited collection
of elements of $x$ is a subset. What I'm wondering is whether this 
axiom gives **all** the "subsets" (in the naive sense). That is, could there exist  a collection of elements of $x$ that cannot be so delimited and is not a set? Or possibly whose status is unknown?

Great care (via new axioms) is taken to show that singletons $\{u\}$ are subsets, and also 
that the union or intersection of sets is a set. The complement of 
a subset should also work via $y^c=\{u\in x: u\notin y\}$. But the general question
seems to be a non-issue in set theory. Is that because the proposition that all 
"subsets" are subsets follows from the ZFC axioms, or that the question is uninteresting?
I suspect that I am just overthinking this...

I also own *Set Theory* by Kenneth Kunen and *Set Theory (3rd edition)* by Thomas Jech
if you want to point me somewhere particular.

---

**Comprehension scheme (or schema of separation)** For every formula $\varphi(s,t)$ with free variables $s$ and $t$, set $x$, and parameter $p$ there exists a set $y=\{u\in x: \varphi(u,p)\}$ that contains all those $u\in x$ that have the property $\varphi$.

Comment: Wow, you really got everything covered. Definability with parameters, without parameters, and external definability. :-)

Comment: IMHO, for all but a few very narrow specialties, Separation and Choice are the about the only axioms of set theory that the "working mathematician" need concern him/herself with when writing informal proofs. (Only a few maniacs like me actually write machine-verified, formal proofs.)  For Separation, you only need to know that you cannot define a subset in terms of itself. You may get into trouble otherwise. For Choice, you only need to know that if you have a family of non-empty sets, you are entitled assume the existence of a function mapping each one of these sets to an element of itself.

Comment: ... the family of sets itself being the domain of this so-called *choice function.*

Comment: BTW, I think you might be missing some kind of restriction on parameter $p$. If you had $p=y$, as Asaf suggests, you would be defining the subset $y$ in terms of itself -- something I have suggested you avoid. You could have any number of other parameters in your selection criteria, just no reference the subset being defined.

Comment: @Dan: There are no restrictions on the parameters in the subset (or replacement) schema. The trick in my answer works when you are given a set and you need to supply a definition *with parameters*. Of course it doesn't work to define every set without parameters.

Comment: See the formal statement of the axiom at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification#Statement Notice that the name of the subset $B$ is not included in the list of parameters following $\varphi$. The superset $A$ can be included, however.

Answer (score 9):

It's certainly possible! There are models of set theory where **every** set is definable, without parameters! http://arxiv.org/abs/1105.4597 In such a model, any "subset" (of some set in the model) which is not definable is not a set.

Meanwhile, it's "usually" the case that there exist nondefinable subsets, although this is of course hard to say precisely. For instance, if $M$ is a model of set theory of size at least $\aleph_2$, then we can find $a, b\in M$ with

- $a$ is a subset of $b$, but
- $a$ is not definable in $M$ in the language of set theory with $b$ as a parameter.

This is a good exercise. (HINT: given that $M$ has size at least $\aleph_2$, find some $b\in M$ such that $(\mathcal{P}(b))^V$ is uncountable.)

---

It's also possible for a model to "miss" subsets of a given set, because they are undefinable: **forcing** is a particularly spectacular way to build instances of a model $M$, an element $b\in M$, and a larger model $N\supseteq M$ such that $N$ "sees" more subsets of $b$ than $M$ does.

Answer (score 8):

Since we allow parameters, everything is definable in the silliest way possible. If you want to define the set $y$, just look at the formula $\varphi(x,p):=x\in y$ with $p=y$.

Now if $A$ is a set, and $y$ is a subset of $A$, then $y$ is defined by that formula, with the suitable parameter.

Of course, if you want to talk about definability without parameters, Noah gave a good answer.

Comment: That's circular.  In ZFC the only things that exist are sets.  You can't pass $y$ as a parameter until after you prove it is a set, which is what you're trying to do.

Comment: No, you already *have* a model. And you *have* $y$. Now you want to find it a definition. And if you allow parameters, which the subset schema allows, then you can in fact use $y$ as a parameter for its own definition.

Comment: But your definition is *in terms of* $y$.  That seems very slippery to me.

Comment: But you're not *proving* the existence of $y$ in terms of $y$. This set *already* exists. There is no circularity.

Comment: When I did math in school, we tended to avoid defining things in terms of themselves.  Does saying "We have a model" excuse that?  I'd like to see more elaboration on that point.

Comment: Usually when you define something, it's to prove its existence. Having a model, means that existence is already given. Having $y$ already in advance means that you don't need to *prove its existence*. But the question was about finding a definition using the subset axiom schema. And since that definition allows parameters, it sort of trivializes down since $y$ already exists and therefore can be used as a parameter.

Comment: So if I have a model of the natural numbers, I can define 1 as "the unique number which is equal to one?"  That just doesn't sound like a definition to me.

Comment: I have said all that I can say. You can sit down and read through a book in set theory, and see what's this is about, or downvote. But I really can't tell you much more than I have. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is possible that there may be subcollections of a set that are not sets.

However, by the comprehension axiom, such a situation can only arise if you have some *external* notion of "subcollection". So as long as you stay "inside" of a set-theoretic universe, all subcollections of sets must actually be sets themselves.

In typical applications, we presume that we are either staying inside of such a universe, or that the model of ZFC is big enough so that all subcollections are actually sets; working with models that are missing some subcollections is something mainly limited to technical set-theoretic or epistemological arguments.

If you're not at the point where you can wrap your head around Skolem's paradox, ignore the following.

If you have a countable model of ZFC, then its set of natural numbers must have only countably many subsets; consequently, "most" of the subcollections of its set of natural numbers are not actually sets of the countable model.

Comment: I like the reverse Skolem paradox: model of ZFC which has an uncountably many finite ordinals. :-)

Comment: Even though I don't know what Skolem's paradox is, I found your final paragraph very useful. It tells me that this pathology *is possible*, but that a beginner in set theory shouldn't spend too much time worrying about it!